# Javascript files not loading consistently?

Tags: javascript, iis, webforms

We have a .net web forms application, running on iis on our own server that has show some strange behaviour in the last 24 hours.

Rollbar notified me of multiple errors all saying certain js functions/variables can't be found from a host of users - essentially breaking the app. I've come into work today, loaded the site up in chrome dev tools only to find it did not have any source file shown, and therefore no js files to load/step through (css & image files are there though).

To make matters more confusing, after refreshing the page everything is there as it should be?!

An updated build of the app was released yesterday, so I'm guessing that has something to do with it?

Honestly any speculative pointers on things we can look into to prevent it happening again would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have multiple JS files and your code is running before it's dependencies are loaded, then you get 'undefined' errors. After refresh files are already cached so they happen to load "in order of inclusion". Try to disable cache in devTools and reload it a few times checking if it is still broken on only first attempt, or maybe always.

Comment: I think the files are ordered correctly, but you're right - It makes sense to bundle them up when deploying, it's a 1 page app that incorporates user controls so there's about 10 js files in total. I'm not sure that was the issue though as they just straight up didn't load the first time I used the page this morning.

Comment: let me know, if that was the issue, then i will move my comment to an answer

Comment: If you wish to move it I'll mark as accepted, we're going to go ahead with it. It's considered good practice so it seems a solid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple javascript files and your code is running before its dependencies are loaded, then you get 'undefined' errors.

After page refresh the dependency files are already cached, so they load immediately, almost synchronously. That's why you dont get errors next times.

Try to disable cache in devTools and reload it a few times checking if next attempts are still working.

If that is the problem, you might consider modularizing your JavaScript code and loading it as asynchronous dependencies, for example by using **browserify**, **webpack** or even **require.js**. Anyways, you can find more in the subject looking for "javascript load order".